# Permissions for adding items to workflow bundles

Tags: workflow, permissions

We need to grant permissions for users to add items to a workflow bundle without granting system administrator permissions to them. I believe we have already granted permissions for the right publications (the ones containing components and pages).

Is this possible? If so, how can this be achieved?

Comment: When you say you believe you have already granted permissions - do you mean you have given the users Bundle Management rights in the relevant Publications?

Comment: Ahh, no, that makes sense. I think I've figured it out now. If we grant Read, Write, Delete access for the required groups to the folder that permissions are inherited from, then that seems to do it, as bundle permissions are then inherited down to the workflow bundle. Thanks for your quick response. That was really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the above comment, if we grant Read, Write, Delete access for the required groups to the folder that permissions are inherited from, then that seems to do it, as bundle permissions are then inherited down to the workflow bundle.